# Can't get rid of DEBUG logs on React-Native development build and socket.io-client

Tags: react-native, socket.io, expo

I use an Expo development build to test my React-Native application on my device.
So I launch it with this command line :

`npx expo start --dev-client`

My app starts, no issues there.
However, I use the socket.io-client library and I keep getting "DEBUG" logs in my Expo console...

**How can I get rid of them ? Are they coming from Expo or from socket.io-client ?**

See the screen below, and the code I used to create a socket.
Thanks for your help :)

[image: socket.io-client]

[image: DEBUG logs]

Comment: It seems they are coming from socket.io-client and the "debug" library... I don't know how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code above the App Component Declaration

```
const debug = console.debug
console.debug = function () {
  if (/engine\.io.*/g.test(arguments[0]) || /socket\.io.*/g.test(arguments[0])) return

  debug(...arguments)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
Sadly, it doesn't change anything. In the socket.io-client module there are several files with a `const debug = ...` and it imports `debug` library. So I'm guessing your answer doesn't override theses instructions.